# Is Type information in Dart tied to is and as operator?

Tags: dart

I have the following **code in Dart Programming Language**.

```
void main() {
    Object i = new A();
    bool b = (i is A);
    print(i.i); // this line gives error
    if (b) {
        print(i.i); // this executes with success
    }
}
```

Also consider this one

```
void main() {
    Object i = new A();
    print(i.i); // this line gives error
    print((i as A).i);
    print(i.i); // this executes with success
}
```

What happens when we use `is` and `as` operators. **Does Dart attaches the type information** when the tests are performed or what?

It is a bit confusing. **Can anyone please help?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `i is A` and `i as A` use runtime type information to check whether `i` is an `A` at runtime. The Dart compiler statically deduces that it can do type *promotion* to treat `i` as an `A` in the cases where `i is A` or `i as A` succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart type inference allows you to *promote* the type of *local variables* in some cases. It's is based on `is` checks and (more rarely) `as` checks.
It requires the compiler to be absolutely sure that the promoted type is still valid where it's being used, so any number of things can disable promotion, with assigning to the promoted variable being the most obvious.

The most basic of promotions is the direct `is` check in a

```dart
  Object i = new A();
  if (i is A) print(i.i);
```

This is valid because the `i is A` check promotes the variable `i` to `A` on the `true`-branch of the `if`.

Then you notice that the test doesn't have to be inside the `if`.

```dart
  Object i = new A();
  bool b = (i is A);
  if (b) print(i.i);
```

This works because the type inference *remembers* the promotion information along with the boolean value, so it knows that if `b` is true, `i` is an `A`.
(Obvious caveats apply: Compiler has to be certain that the result is still valid at the `if` statement, so basically the same constraints as for type promotion.)

The `as` promotion works by treating `x as T` as if it was `(x is T ? x : (throw TypeError(....)))`, so all the code afterwards is in the `true` branch of that test, because the `false` branch threw instead of continuing.

Comment: That logically makes sense

Answer (score 0):

In Dart programming language,
is and as are used for type checking and type casting respectively.

Comment: That is not the question.

Comment: Of course, Dart attaches type information when using is and as operators. The is operator tests whether an object is an instance of a particular type. If the test succeeds, the object is guaranteed to be of that type at runtime. The as operator performs a type cast and returns the object as the specified type if it is not null and is an instance of that type. If the object is not an instance of the specified type, a runtime error occurs.